# Missing paths in parent child hierarchy

Tags: sql, sas, hierarchy, proc

I have created a flat hierarchy SAS data set. There are 
duplicates in the data, but the hierarchy SAS data set is missing some sub 
trees. For some of the parent's children I cannot backtrack them to the original one.

For example:

```
                ->M->P->Q  
    4->A->B->C-|
                ->F->H
```

In this example I can't backtrack from F to 4, but from M,P,Q there is path to 4.

I have both entries for C in the hierarchy table. That is:

```
        C->M->P->Q and 
        C->F->H
```

But there is only one entry for 4. That is:

```
       4->A->B->C->M->P->Q
```

Another entry for 4 should be:

```
       4->A->B->C->F->H
```

But this entry is missing.

I am trying with self join, but without success. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Show the code you wrote for **"I am trying with self join..."**.  Are the node values unique amongst all nodes at all levels ?  If not you might get false segment linkages or cycles.  Are you trying to output a dataset of all complete paths from a dataset containing paths and segments ? Is the hierarchy data two columns, `childId` `parentId`, or an actual string `Id->Id->Id...`

Comment: Which SAS `proc` are you using?

Comment: What sort of output are you attempting to produce? Please post sample input and desired output datasets to go with your diagrams.